# Yii Search in navigation menu

Tags: search, menu, yii

I'm currently writing an application in Yii in which i want to create a search box in the header (either in the navigation menu or just above it). This search box should be able to be accessed from every part of the site, and it should be able to search on different columns of different tables.

I have no idea on how to do this, and almost all posts on the web about it involves using the grid-view, or an extension (I'd like to create the code without an extension if that's possible).

Do you have an idea to how the search code should look (what i should put in which controller etc.)?

-- EDIT --

I still don't know how to do this but I will show you what I have at the moment anyway. It is not much and it is pretty obvious where i am missing some code.

/view/layout/main.php:

```
<?php echo CHtml::form(Yii::app()->createUrl('product/search'), 'get') ?>
            <?php echo CHtml::textField('search_key','',array('placeholder' => 'Search')); ?>
            <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Go'); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::endForm() ?>
```

/view/product/search.php:

```
//Not sure by any means what to write here, but I'll like a list view populated with the search results
```

/controllers/productController.php

```
/**
 * Search through model.
 */
public function actionSearch()
{
    if(isset($_GET['search_key'])){
        $search = $_GET['search_key'];  
        $model->name = $search;  
    }       

    $this -> render('search', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

/models/Product.php

```
/**
 * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
 * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
 */
public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

Comment: I didn't do it, but I imagine you would need: Input field, submit button. Method Search in your controller with params needed, or 'title' by default. Then this method creates a CActiveDataProvider and renders a page showing a CGridView having the POST's found with TITLE = title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can perform like this:

Find `#mainmeu` in `/protected/views/layout/main.php`

```
<div id="mainmenu">
    <div style="width: 80%;float: right">
        <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
                array('label'=>'about', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
                array('label'=>'contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
            ),
        )); ?>
    </div>

    <div style='float: left;direction: rtl; color: #ffffff; margin: 5px 0 0 5px; font-size: 13px'>
        <?php echo CHtml::form(Yii::app()->createUrl('product/search'),'get') ?>
            <?php echo CHtml::textField('search_key', 'search') ?>
            <?php echo CHtml::submitButton(); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::endForm() ?>
    </div>
</div><!-- mainmenu -->
```

## Edit:

**/models/Product.php:**

```
public function search()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

**/controllers/productController.php -> actionSearch():**

```
public function actionSearch()
{
    $model = new Product('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();
    if(isset($_GET['search_key'])) 
        $model->name = $_GET['search_key'];     

    $this -> render('search', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

**/view/product/search.php:**

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'product-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    //'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'name',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

Comment: well, i kind of know where i want it already (the same spot you pointed out), i'm just very much in doubt on how my search code should look?

Comment: simply write a `html form`. is there any question?

Comment: I can't see how just writing a html form would do the trick? I've never made a search box before so perhaps i just see it in a too complicated way. How would you write this html form in order to redirect to a page containing a list view of the search results?

Comment: **@Deram** I changed the code in the current edition. Solved?

Comment: Not really, I'm still missing the whole search logic. When I try to search something with the code you just gave me, I'm just redirected to the search page.

Comment: **@Deram** You would deal with the sent form. your try it? can you put your code?

Comment: **@Deram** In your `actionSearch` you used `$model->name`, where you defined `$model` variable? it must be an instance of `Model`. like: `$model = new Model(search);`

Comment: **@Deram** If you want the problem to be solved, please put your whole code of `Model`, `searchAction`, `View`.

Comment: **@Deram** I hope in edited my answer, get your answer, if it's please mark the answer as accepted answer.